# How to call a controller method from AngularJS

Tags: apex, visualforce, angularjs

I'm loading the tree-view structure as shown below when the user clicks on the parent/child it spit on the console.log but i'm not sure how to pass the clicked parent/child node to apex controller

```
       $scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch) {
            console.log('you clicked on', branch);
            //how to pass the branch to controller ?????? 
        }
```

Screen shot:

[image]
This is the code:

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['treeGrid']);

    // controller
    myApp.controller('treeGridController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        var tree;
        var rawTreeData = {!JSONData};
        var myTreeData = getTree(rawTreeData, 'Id', '{!relationshipFieldName}');

        $scope.tree_data = myTreeData;
        $scope.my_tree = tree = {};
        $scope.expanding_property = {
            field: "Name",
            displayName: "Name",
            sortable : true,
            filterable: true
        };
        $scope.col_defs = {!FieldsJSON};
        $scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch) {
            console.log('you clicked on', branch);
            //how to pass the branch to controller ?????? 
        }
        //..........
</script>
```

I have read that you can use `apex:actionFunction` but in my situation I need to set the values user have clicked.

EDIT:
I have tried using javascript remoting function but getting the following error:

> Visualforce Remoting Exception: Method 'mymethod' not found on
>   controller RN_sObjectHierarchy. Check spelling, method exists, and/or
>   method is RemoteAction annotated.

```
$scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch,scope) { 
                  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                   "RN_sObjectHierarchy.mymethod", branch.param,
                        function(result, event) {
                            if(result) {
                                scope.$apply(function(){
                                scope.result = result;

                                });
                                // something more to do?
                            } else {
                                console.log("There was an error");
                            } 
                        },
                   {escape: false} // No escaping, please
              );
        }
```

Controller:

```
@RemoteAction
public static void mymethod(String name){
    system.debug('///' +  name);
}
```

Comment: This might help get you started, I showed how to add a `RemoteAction` to your module a while back: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112617/bad-practice-to-invoke-remoteaction-on-page-load-from-static-resource/112648#112648

Comment: Make sure the method is in same controller which is defined in visualforce page also it had proper annotation, return type etc. as per javascript specification

Comment: yes the method is in the same controller, do you see anything wrong with the above code? that i posted in EDIT section

Comment: if you want to give it a shot, here is the github https://github.com/RatanPaul/sObjectHierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I able to get the selected row in the controller through JS remoting.

```
$scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch,scope) {         
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('RN_sObjectHierarchy.mymethod', branch,
            function(result, event){
              //alert(result);
              //alert(event);
            },
            {escape: false}
            );
    }
```

Controller Class:

```
@RemoteAction
public static void mymethod(String branch){
    system.debug('///selectedRow:' +  branch);              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript remoting function inside the Angular function:-

```
$scope.my_tree_handler = function (branch,scope) { 
      Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                   "ApexClassName.classMethod", branch.param,
                        function(result, event) {
                            if(result) {
                                scope.$apply(function(){
                                scope.result = result;

                                });
                                // something more to do?
                            } else {
                                console.log("There was an error");
                            } 
                        },
                   {escape: false} // No escaping, please
      );
}
```

Note the `scope.$apply`. This is how you set the value again. Remoting functions are asynchronous so results won't be reflected as soon as you click. It will be dependent on how soon you get the result.

You need to make sure that you always have `$scope` instance in function.

Comment: This approach won't work within a `Static Resource`, however. If you're developing a sophisticated `Javascript` application, it probably shouldn't be all shoved in one `Visualforce Page`. But that's just my opinion, man.

Comment: It works! there is no expression binding. It depends on how good we structure/design javascript approach in application. @AdrianLarson

Comment: @Ashwani: I have updated my question and I have tried but did not work, i pasted detail.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Since the controller method argument is a regular string, you can just do `window.classMethodFQN = '{!$RemoteAction.classMethod}'` on your Visualforce page/component, then call it with `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(classMethodFQN, ...)` in a static resource.  `window` can of course be replaced with `scope` or any other object.