# Read JavaScript Array into Apex List

Tags: apex, json

This question is related to what I have asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151378/how-to-call-a-controller-method-from-angularjs/151393#151393)

I'm getting this output in my apex controller and I'm looking a way to extract or parse this output string into List or Class?

```
18:59:48:001 USER_DEBUG [21]|DEBUG|--debuglogbranch:
{attributes={type=Account, url=/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/0014100000BNrJEAA1}, 
   Id=0014100000BNrJEAA1, Name=test2, ParentId=00141000009mTavAAE, 
   children=[
    {
       attributes={type=Account, 
       url=/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/0014100000BNrLIAA1},     
       Id=0014100000BNrLIAA1, Name=test2.2, 
       ParentId=0014100000BNrJEAA1, 
       level=3, 
       expanded=false, 
       uid=0.7055100027498606, 
       parent_uid=0.11747820325450764, 
       children=[]
     }
    ], 
    level=2, 
    expanded=true, 
    uid=0.11747820325450764, 
    parent_uid=0.33335628016211594, 
    selected=true
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
@RemoteAction
public static void mymethod(String branch){
Map<String, Object> root = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(branch);
    List<Object> items = (List<Object>)root.get('attributes'); //ERROR
    for (Object item : items) {
        Map<String, Object> i = (Map<String, Object>)item;
        System.debug(i.get('id'));
    }
}
```

got this error:

```
> Visualforce Remoting Exception: , column 1: Invalid conversion
> from runtime type String to Map<String,ANY>
```

Comment: Use [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/0014100000BNrJEAA1&autoExec=1) to check returned json

Comment: `"attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/0014100000BNrLIAA1"
  },
  "Id" : "0014100000BNrLIAA1",`

Comment: do you a link how you check the returned type in workbench

Comment: okay i'm in the workbench and i see the account record but where do you see the returned type?

Answer (score 2):

I hit a very similar issue to this the other day, I didn't bother trying to establish why this works but I found that going via an intermediate variable helped, but I was indexing the list directly because I only cared about the first entry:

```
List<Object> messageResults = (List<Object>)resBody.get('messages');
Map<String, Object> messageResult = (Map<String, Object>)messageResults[0];
```

A sub-standard workaround for your scenario *might* be to use a regular for loop:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    Map<String, Object> item = (Map<String, Object>)items[i];
    System.debug(item.get('id'));
}
```

Although you'd expect `Object` to be a pure reference to any object there is definitely some funkiness around how it's been implemented; I've hit a scenario before where some code just wouldn't work as expected when using it.

Comment: You just said line 27... without any line numbers ;)

Try splitting that in two maybe:
 Object tempItems = (Object)root.get('attributes');
 List<Object> items = (List<Object>)tempItems;

Comment: even after splitting that into two getting the error `column 1: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to List<ANY>`

Comment: That's because `"attributes"` maps to a `Map<String, Object>`, not a `List<Object>`. Key-value pairs.